# My CSS animation does not work

Tags: html, css

I have some animation pull down that supposed to work on all browsers but it is not working on any.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scroll-indicator-wrapper">
    <div class="scroll-indicator"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .scroll-indicator-wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 45px/2);
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.scroll-indicator {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    background: // some background
    background-size: 22px 14px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: pulseDown 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: pulseDown 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: pulseDown 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: please show us code of your animation (@keyframes). you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: It's hard for me to understand why this question was upvoted. The tooltip on upvote says: ***This question shows research effort. It is useful and clear.*** What research effort? It's not useful or clear for anyone who doesn't already know the answer and a simple search for CSS animations how-tos would be a lot more useful to anyone trying to learn. I knew SO standards were dropping, just didn't know they did it at such an alarming pace...